# Tinymce doesn't perform browser spell check when pasted data

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-4

Tried all the options like `paste_preprocess` & `paste_postprocess` but spell check only happens if there are no new lines in the pasted content.

P.S: I do not want a server to be included as this is an offline app.

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: uniqueId,
   schema: 'html5',
   mode: 'exact',
   elementpath: false,
   height: 125,
   menubar: false,
   resize: false,
   browser_spellcheck: true,
   plugins: ['paste table wordcount lists fullscreen'],
   toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | paste pastetext | bold italic underline | subscript superscript | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | table | fullscreen'
});
```